# Number of characters in a string having numeric pattern (in R)?

Tags: r, string, character, counting

I look for a **function** (say, ncharexact) that will return the number of characters in a string having numeric pattern. Observe:

```
nchar(5.00) # 1
nchar("5.00") # 4; this is what I desire: ncharexact(5.00)=4

nchar(5.00120) # 6 (the last 0 is not taken into account) 
nchar("5.00120") # 7; this is what I desire: ncharexact(5.00120)=7
nchar(5.0012000) # 6 (the last 000 is not taken into account) 
nchar("5.0012000") # 9; this is what I desire: ncharexact(5.0012000)=9
```

When I try to write the code of ncharexact function (though it seems easy at first glance), I could not succeed no matter what.

*What I faced:*
String concatenation, adding single quote, and adding double quote to a string seemed to me the relevant tools. I found them:

**Adding single quote to string**
convert abc to 'abc':
(1)

```
paste("'", "abc", "'", sep="")  # "'abc'"
```

(2)

```
paste0("'", "abc", "'") # "'abc'"
```

(3)

```
sQuote("abc") # "‘abc’" (shape of single quote different!)
options("useFancyQuotes") # Default=TRUE
options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE) 
sQuote("abc") # "'abc'" (shape of single quote upright ASCII!)
options(useFancyQuotes = TRUE) # Return to default value
```

(4)

```
Reduce(paste0,list("'","abc","'")) # "'abc'"
```

(5)

```
mapply(paste0, "'", c("abc", "def"), "'")
#       '    <NA> 
#   "'abc'" "'def'"
```

Also,

```
library(stringr)
mystring <- "123 AB 246 CD"
v <- str_extract_all(mystring, '[0-9]{3} [A-Z]{2}')[[1]];v   # "123 AB" "246 CD"
r <- paste0(v, collapse='","', sep="");r                  # "123 AB\",\"246 CD"
singlequote <- paste0("'",paste0(v, sep="", collapse="','"),"'"); singlequote # "'123 AB','246 CD'"
```

**Adding double quote to string**

```
shQuote("abc") # "\"abc\""  Appearance is bad, but it works
```

The above seems not to convert abc string to "abc" string at first glance, but it exactly really does:
reverse slashes are not part of string. Each charaster can be seen:

```
strsplit(shQuote("abc"), "") # "\"" "a"  "b"  "c"  "\""
nchar(shQuote("abc")) # 5; there are only 5 characters
```

If one wants string (to be showed) without reverse slashes:

```
cat(shQuote("abc"), "\n") # "abc"
nchar(cat(shQuote("abc"), "\n")) # "abc" integer(0); Appearance is good, but it does not work
```

If we want double quotes to be part of string, we place "\" before it for escaping double quote:

```
"a \"b\" c" # "a \"b\" c"
nchar("a \"b\" c") # 7
```

Comment: `paste0("nchar(\"", 5.00, "\")") # "nchar(\"5\")"` ".00" is evaporated and 5.00 is contracted to 5!

Comment: `nchar("5.00") # 4`. The problem is how to convert to a function to the desired job. You are placing "abc". But, the function seems to require string concatenation, adding single quote to string, adding double quote to string etc.

Comment: A user gave an answer that was OK to me: `nchar(paste0(", 5.00120, ")) - 4 # 7` and `nchar(paste0(", 5.0012000, ")) - 4 # 9` and `nchar(paste0(", -0.1250, ")) - 4 # 7` and `nchar(paste0(", -0.12500000, ")) - 4 # 11`. I did not understand why s/he deleted the answer. I would tick it as answer.

Comment: Now, I discover his/her solution was _NOT_ working: `ncharexact <- function (x) { nchar(paste0(", x, ")) - 4 }` See `nchar(paste0(", 5.00120, ")) - 4 # 7` is correctly working, but when put in a form of function, smt strange happens, and does not work: `ncharexact(5.00120) # 1`. This "1" is the character number of "x". If I put mynumber instead of x as argument, ncharexact would produce 8!

Comment: @Sotos Did you try your regex solution inside a formal function definition? `nchar(paste0(", x, ")) - 4` soluiton fails when put in a formal function definition. Maybe, your regex solution would also fail.

Comment: @Sotos, when I try to understand, solve and implement your idea, your comment was disappeared. Sorry, if I didn't react punctually.